# Assigning a range of variables to another variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables

I am trying to write a macro with some variables. Specifically worksheet names. Almost each time I have to find the correct worksheet name within the macro, so the worksheet names are coming from cell values. But referring a variable to another variable is giving an error.

Down below you can see the assign part of the codes. I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you so much..

```
Dim pLastRow As Long
Dim p As Integer


    pLastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets(WS_All).Range("AA22:AA1100"))
    pLastRow2 = pLastRow + 21
        For p = 22 To pLastRow2
                If Cells(p, 26).Value = "" Then
                    WS_1 = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 16).Value
                    WS_2 = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 19).Value
                    WS_3 = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 22).Value
                End If
Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To 3
Dim j_WS As Variant
j_WS = "WS_" & j
MsgBox Worksheets(j_WS).Cells(1, 1).Value
o = 14 + j * 3
Dim WA1 As String
Dim WA2 As String
Dim WA3 As String
Gorev = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, o).Value
SlideNo = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(p, 34).Value
Egitim_Adi = Worksheets(WS_All).Cells(2, 3).Value
Dim Check1 As Range
Set Check1 = Worksheets(j_WS).Columns("A")   'Egitim_Adi Kontrolü için'
Dim Check2 As Range
Set Check2 = Worksheets(j_WS).Columns("B")  'SlideNo Kontrolü için'
Dim Check3 As Range
Set Check3 = Worksheets(j_WS).Columns("C")  'Gorev Kontrolü için'
```

Comment: As you can see, WS_1, WS_2 and WS_3 values are coming from a worksheet named WS_All, which is also predefined from a range.

What I want to do is to have another worksheet names based on the rows of these worksheets ( WS_1 ... ) and they are called WA1, WA2 and WA3.

I want to use the WA1, WA2 and WA3 with range called " j ", and using them with j_WS.

When I run the code with F8, I see that j_WS is equal to WS_1 or WS_2. But I want j_WS to be equal to the value of WS_1 which is a real worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution with using array and using 3 cases for WS_1, 2 and 3.